# Finding Geometric Mean of user input

Tags: c++, mean

I am working on a project for a class and I am having trouble with the output of the geometric mean, which always come out to be 1 and I'm sure that isn't right.

Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>

#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char**argv) 
{
float i, j, k;
float a, h, g;

cout<<"Enter 3 floating point numbers"<<endl;
cin>>i>>j>>k;

while(i>0 && j>0 && k>0 )
{
    a = (i+j+k)/3;
    h = 3/((1/i) + (1/j) + (1/k));


    g = pow((i*j*k),(1/3));

    cout<<"Arithmetic: "<<a<<endl;
    cout<<"Harmonic: "<<h<<endl;
    cout<<"Geometric: "<<g<<endl;

    cout<<"Enter 3 floating point numbers"<<endl;
    cin>>i>>j>>k;
}


return(0);
}
```

Comment: You should use a debugger to try and figure out what part of the calculation is failing.

Comment: Google: "c++ geometric mean" and look for the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1/3` is an integer equal to `0`. You should write `1.0/3.0` (or `1./3`) to get a floating point value.

Comment: I'd split the difference and write `1.0/3`.

Comment: That's because you're a numeratist. :-) I think `<chrono>` provides `std::ratio`, maybe there's a C++ way to obtain fractions in a generic way...

Answer (score 4):

`1/3` is zero, because it is integral division. It always is integral division if both operands are of integral types. Then you do the power of something to zero and get one.

You need to use floating-point literals: `1.0/3.0` would have type `double` and `1.0f/3.0f` would have type `float`.

Comment: "*Would* have"? Under what condition?

Comment: @Kerrek: under the condition that he writes it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(1/3)
```

This is an integral division that always produces 0, as the remainder is deifned to be truncated. You need to cast one or both to a floating-point value.

Comment: Cast? The language offers convenient floating point literals!